# Constrains warning in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I need to fix some warning of constrains in storyboard.
My button have left and right fixes constrains and height.
It's work great in all devices but i do not [image: know] how to remove warning

Thanks a lot

Comment: What warning you are getting in storyboard?

Comment: Fixed leading and trailing constraints may cause clipping, one of them should have a constants > standard space

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For removing warning --

Remove leading and trailing constraints

and set proportional width from superview like

[image]

[image]

and center horizontally in superview like-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the above image, I can see there are additional constraints for top margin and bottom margin. If you are setting the fixed height constraint then you need to choose either top margin or bottom margin for alignment. So, quick fix is to delete 1 out of these two (top or bottom).

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Leading or Trailing constraint give.
2. Constant 8 or minimum gap you need.
3. Change Relation to Grater than or Equal.

[image]